# How can I access the data via JS from closed JSON object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

The response is coming from the API. The response object is mentioned below:

```
               {
                   "abc": [{
                              "xyz": "INFO 1",
                              "pqr": "INFO 2"
                            },
                            {
                              "xyz": "INFO 3",
                              "pqr": "INFO 4"
                          }]
                }
```

The expected value from the response object is:

`xyz, INFO 1`
`xyz, INFO 3`

Could you help to retrieve these values from the response object?

Comment: First, convert it to a JS object `JSON.parse(jsonString)`. Then you can access the data via JS.

Comment: You have an object which has one property "abc" which is an array of objects. If you do as commented above, you will get this object, you can then reference the obj.abc and iterate the array to get the "xyz" property of each object in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert JSON to JS object - `JSON.parse(jsonString)`
2. Use standard [dot notation and bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to retrieve the values (e.g. `JSobject.abc[0].xyz`)

```js
const object = {
  "abc": [{
      "xyz": "INFO 1",
      "pqr": "INFO 2"
    },
    {
      "xyz": "INFO 3",
      "pqr": "INFO 4"
    }
  ]
}

console.log(object.abc[0].xyz)
```

If you know the structure of the JSON you're getting you can also iterate through it to get all the data at once:

```js
const object = {
  "abc": [{
      "xyz": "INFO 1",
      "pqr": "INFO 2"
    },
    {
      "xyz": "INFO 3",
      "pqr": "INFO 4"
    }
  ]
}

object.abc.forEach(o => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(p => {
    console.log(`${p}, ${o[p]}`)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `JSON.parse` and `.map` to get a flat array of "xyz"

```js
const json = '{ "abc": [{ "xyz": "INFO 1", "pqr": "INFO 2" }, { "xyz": "INFO 3", "pqr": "INFO 4" }] }';
const jobj = JSON.parse(json);
const xyzs = jobj.abc.map((a) => a.xyz);
console.log(xyzs);
```